# File/files that is/are responsible for password aging in solaris

Tags: solaris, password

What file/files is/are responsible for password aging in solaris server? Whenever a user is added, the default password aging limit is 90 days right? So is there a config file responsible for this?

Comment: If you expire passwords, then users will choose simple passwords. See https://xkcd.com/936/ for how to choose a good password.

Comment: Relevant recommendations from US government FTC:  https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/blogs/techftc/2016/03/time-rethink-mandatory-password-changes  NIST Special Publication 800-63B ([Google cached](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_-clXRWXyu8J:https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html)) also eliminates requirements to age off passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Solaris.

```
grep MAXWEEKS /etc/defaults/passwd
```

Comment: But does this contain the per-user setting, or (as the name suggests) is it just the ***default*** when a new user is created?

Comment: @G-Man I couldn't find any content in question that OP  is asking for the user based expiry, for that we can do `passwd -x max username` , where `max` is the maximum age limit for the current password.

Comment: You're right; the question *is* ambiguous.

Comment: @G-Man This is the default when a new user is created.

Comment: @msp9011 The command which you have specified in the comment section is for a specific user which was not what I meant

p.s- Is there a way where i can avoid local authentication and use some other server to authenticate? Assuming in both the servers the users are same.

Comment: @Mr.AG then we should look something like LDAP...

Comment: Search for “[authentication server](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=authentication+server)”. I’ve heard of [RADIUS](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/RADIUS), but I have no experience (or affiliation) with it.

Comment: @msp9011 how do you find if a user is locally authenticated or not? I checked the passwd and shadow but those parameters are not helping much!

Comment: @msp9011 so if I modify MAXWEEKS as MAXWEEKS = -1 will it mean that for all users who are created in the future their password won't expire?